# Is it possible to aggregate an object instad of a string with spring cloud stream api?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I want to use the spring cloud stream api to aggreate events from a topic.
Therefore i use as input a KStream.

```
KStream<Object, LoggerCreatedMessage>
```

Now i want to use an aggregator to store my new Object in a KeyValue Store, so i use following code:

```
input
  .map((key, value) -> {
    return new KeyValue<>(value.logger_id,value);
  })
  /*.groupBy(
    (s, loggerEvent) -> loggerEvent.logger_id,
    Serialized.with(null, loggerEventSerde))*/
  .groupByKey()
  .aggregate(
    String::new,
    (s, loggerEvent, vr) -> {
      return vr;
    },
    Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(STORE_NAME).withKeySerde(Serdes.String()).
      withValueSerde(Serdes.String())
  );
```

Why can i only use a String as an Initializer is it not possible to use any Object?

Instead of String::new i wanted to use LoggerDomain::new, but i only get this error message:

> Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert LoggerDomain to VR

Do i miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `<key,value>` as `<String, String>` via `Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>` -- if you value type should be `LoggerDomain`, it should be `Materialized.<KeyType, LoggerDomain, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>()`.

Note that you need to provide a custom `Serde` for `LoggerDomain` for this case to `Materialized`, too.